# How do I represent a diffusive source that involve coordinate?

Tags: fipy

C(h) \frac{\partial h}{\partial t}=\nabla \cdot(K(h) \nabla(h+z))
I have two questions:

1. How do I represent a diffusive source that involve coordinate? The
   governing equation is for h; k(h) is a function of h; z was the z
   coordinate. I knew how to write a diffusive source without the
   coordinate z, but I did not know how to represent a diffusive source
   that involve coordinate.

   2. Do "phi[0].updateOld()"in the "...\fipy\examples\diffusion\mesh1D.py" update the "eq =transientTerm() == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D0 * (1 - phi[0]))" when just
      use "res = eq.sweep(var=phi[0], dt=timeStepDuration)"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 2):

1. [image: equation using Online Equation Editor]

and

[image: equation using Online Equation Editor]

so

[image: equation using Online Equation Editor]

The second term on the RHS is then written explicitly as `(K(h).faceValue * [[0], [0], [1]]).divergence`.

If `K(h)` is a linear function of `h`, then you could express this as a `ConvectionTerm`. E.g., if `K(h) = h * K1(h)`, then you could write `ConvectionTerm(coeff=K1(h).faceValue * [[0], [0], [1]])`.

2. Do you mean, does `coeff=D0 * (1 - phi[0])` get updated? Yes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I test the (Krel*[[0],[1]]).divergence for 2D mesh, but it showed"AttributeError: 'binOp' object has no attribute 'divergence'".So I changed it to "(Krel.faceValue*[[0],[1]]).divergence". Now it works. But  I was confused by the "facevalue". Which "facevalue"should be used?

Comment: you mean "psi.updateOld()" update all coeff related to psi. If I want "psi_tmp=psi" did not update. How can I deal with it?

Comment: @Liu: Yes, you're right. It should be `K(h).faceValue`. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Liu: Please ask 2. as a separate question. StackOverflow isn't conducive to answering independent questions like this.

Comment: I read other tag in [fipy]. Found "psi_tmp=psi.copy()" is work. Thanks for your answers.